# ubuntu & asus laptop graphics card problem

Tags: 14.04, graphics

I've just purchased a brand new [asus laptop](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X550ZE/specifications/) and I want to put ubuntu 14.04 on it.

From the install phase I encountered problems with the graphic card, it does not function properly.

I was able to use the option "try ubuntu without installing" to boot into it, but here the same problem, as you can see in the [screen shoot](http://s20.postimg.org/7vubds8zf/IMG_20150321_085548.jpg).
Strangely, the task bar it is displayed correctly. That is a terminal window opened on the screen, btw. Any window or program that I open looks like that.

This is the model of the graphic card: AMD Radeon® R5 M230 + Radeon® R7 M270 DX Dual Graphics with 2GB DDR3 VRAM Built-in FX-7600P

Any ideas how to solve this? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Fist step after an installation always is to upgrade all packages including open source graphic drivers to get bugs fixed. This can be done from a terminal or TTY even if graphics are not working:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

In general, for an AMD card, the Open Source `radeon` driver is supported very well and should only be replace by a proprietary driver in case of issues.

If **after that** we still had grahics card issues we should proceed using the tested drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories accessible via *System settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers* (**proprietary drivers (restricted) repository needs to be activated first**):

[image]
<sup>Here shown for Nvidia</sup>

If **after that** the issue was not resolved we may look for a [repository, a ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them?s=4%7C0.0000) or a Debian package providing a more recent graphics driver for **your specific** AMD card. This will already **introduce a high risk of making your system instable** but in case your system breaks at least it can usually be reverted.

**Only if after all that** the issue still was not resolved we may try our luck with downloading the bleeding edge untested newest and possibly buggy driver from the manufacturer website. This may also involve runnign a proprietary installation with a custom-made install script. In case our system does not work afte that we **can not easily revert the changes** we had made. So this step really should be a last resort reserved for rare cases that can not be resolved otherwise (e.g. a brand new high end card). Before you do that you should read other people's experiences, and you should also be sure that your issue will be resolved.

Also see

- [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)
- [AMD/ATI drivers from website vs. proprietary drivers in Ubuntu 12.04 Repos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133398/amd-ati-drivers-from-website-vs-proprietary-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-04-repos)

Comment: -1 Proprietary drivers provided by AMD for its latest hardware are not "bleeding edge, untested, newest, nor possibly buggy". AMD thouroughly tests their drivers before release.

Comment: @darksky: well from what I see here we can not say that there are no bugs or issues with proprietary AMD drivers: http://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=fglrx - you may have just been lucky but I've heard of too many unfortunate users to recommend this as a first step to do.

Comment: I agree that in the past, some people have experienced some issues with installing drivers. But I would not use that as circumstantial evidence that all of AMD's drivers are broken altogether. It's like looking up all the problems people have with their TV's and then conclude you should never buy a TV. Their Linux drivers have matured in the past few years, and now they even have a Ubuntu-specific driver which should work quite nicely with 14.04.

Comment: Looking a bit further into it, you might have confused [AMD's beta/experimental drivers](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx) with their [stable release](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064). There is a clear distinction between the two. Beta drivers are bleeding edge and prone to bugs and instability, but mainline releases are not.

Comment: @darksky: from my heart I feel that **all drivers should be Open Source**. Proprietary drivers using proprietary installation procedures other than our package management always introduce a high risk for system stability (independent of the driver's release state). And no, I do not confuse the beta drivers with the final release drivers, I only observe what people experience after a failed install of downloaded drivers. That said, I applaud AMD's developers for their contribution to the `radeon` driver but at the same time I can't understand why we still depend so much on proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The drivers for all of AMD's graphic cards are at their website here http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/. The first thing you should do is to download the appropriate driver(s) for your system.

Next, install the operating system. Don't worry if the graphics don't work after install. Once system boots up, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to one of [virtual consoles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33078/what-is-a-virtual-terminal-for). From there you can install the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the Ubuntu 14.04 is too old for your graphics card (both card and the OS are released almost at the same time). The Live-mode runs free driver from the Linux kernel which can't handle your graphics card properly.

So, try [Ubuntu 14.04.4](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#Updated_Packages) that ships modern kernel 4.2. If the graphics will fail again try to go to the virtual console (as described in one of the answers to your question) and install latest proprietary driver (AMD Catalyst).

Also please upload the probe of your computer to the [Linux-Hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/) so that we can share your experience for developers.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem in 2022 with a smililar chipset on an Asus laptop. (I tried other Linux distributions, too, including  Fedora and Debian with with X.org and Ubuntu with X.orf and with Wayland.

The critical point is that I was able to log into console (Ctrl-Alt-F2), but not in the graphical environment.

I was able to resolve this problem (with any didtribution) by blacklisting the Radeon driver / module.

It took me quite a long time to figure this out.

I believe we should contact the radeon driver developers team.

This is how you blacklist the radeon module:

Edit (or create) the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf as super user.

Add the line

```
blacklist radeon
```

Run

```
 $ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

(If a Fedora user comes upon this forum, run

```
 # dracut --regenerate-all --force
```

)

Then, reboot your computer. Double-check that radeon is blacklisted by runnning

Here are the chipset details:

```
# lspci -v



  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV620/M82 [Mobility Radeon HD 3450/3470] (prog-if 00 [VGA co
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 19e2
    ....
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon


  #lshw -c video

    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: RV620/M82 [Mobility Radeon HD 3450/3470]
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         ....
         configuration: ******** driver=radeon latency=0
```